# How to create means test table and a cross tabulation table

Tags: r

I have been struggling with this for the past few days, I won't bore you with a post of the various failures...

Below is what I am trying to answer:

Calculate a cross-tabulation that allows you to test the following hypothesis:
•   In a comparison of citizens, women were more likely than men to vote in the 2012 election.

To answer this question, complete Table 1 below.  Include column percentages and cell frequencies in parentheses.  Below the table, include a sentence that explains the result of the test.

Table 1: Gender and Turnout in 2012

See the link at the bottom for pictures of the tables I am trying to create.

As a side note, examine the rate of turnout among both men and women.  Do you think respondents are over-reporting turnout?

6. Perform a comparison of means that allows you to test the following hypothesis:
   •   In a comparison of citizens, Republicans are more likely to feel unfavorably toward the federal government than Democrats.

To do this, complete Table 2 below.  Then include a sentence that explains the result of the test.

Table 2: PID and Federal Government Thermometer Rating (3-point PID scale)

Extra Credit (2pts) Construct a hypothesis using two variables from the NES2012 dataset. State your hypothesis, identify your IV and DV, and then present a table that tests that hypothesis using either cross-tabulation (like in problem 5) or a comparison of means (like in problem 6).

The first table :

[image: This is the first table[1]]

The second table:

[image: This is the second table[2]]

Comment: Thanks for the edits jay.sf! :)

Comment: This is what I have built so far for the first table:   gendercum.freq <- cumsum(table(NES2012_PS3$gender))
 genderfreq <- table(NES2012_PS3$gender)
 genderpercentage <- prop.table(table(NES2012_PS3$gender))
 gendercumulative <- cumsum(prop.table(table(NES2012_PS3$gender)))
 votedcum.freq <- cumsum(table(NES2012_PS3$voted2012))
 votedfreq <- table(NES2012_PS3$voted2012)
 votedpercentage <- prop.table(table(NES2012_PS3$voted2012))
 votedcumulative <- cumsum(prop.table(table(NES2012_PS3$voted2012)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Reading the data

I downloaded the NES2012 data [here](https://edge.sagepub.com/sites/default/files/full%20version.zip), then read the `NES2012.sav` it with `foreign` pacakge.

```
library(foreign)

data <- read.spss(file = "NES2012.sav",
                  to.data.frame = T,
                  use.value.labels = T)
```

Make sure to use value labels and read it as a data.frame

## Contingency table

```
t1<-table(data$gender,data$voted2012)
print(t1)
```

Console output:

```
                   Did not vote Voted
-1. Inapplicable            0     0
Male                      537  2137
Female                    572  2267
```

We have a level for the missing values in the gender variable we can subset/recode the dataset but, in this case, we can simply subset the table

```
t1 <- t1[2:3,] # pick the second to the third row and al the columns
print(t1)
```

Console output:

```
          Did not vote Voted
Male            537  2137
Female          572  2267
```

Now the percentage, we use prop.table and multiply then round

```
pt <- round(prop.table(t1) * 100,2)
```

You can add margins with apply or cumsum or rowsum but addmargins is the easiest one.

```
ptm <- addmargins(pt)
```

Now change the names

```
colnames(ptm)[3] <- "Total" # only the third one
rownames(ptm)[3] <- "Total" # same thing

print(ptm)
```

Console output:

```
        Did not vote  Voted  Total
Male           9.74  38.76  48.50
Female        10.38  41.12  51.50
Total         20.12  79.88 100.00
```

## Mean comparison

I am assuming that the test you are using is the ANOVA, because of of-of the level of the questions it seems to me like an introductory course of statistics or quantitative methods in SSCC. But without knowing the measurement scale of the " Federal Government Thermometer Rating" I wouldn't recommend this method. Just for tackling the assignment let's go with it!. With the ANOVA we work under the null hipotesisis (H0:) that there is no difference between the means.

- **H0: mean(X[Republican]) == mean(X[Democrat]) == mean(X[Independent])**
- **H1: at least one of the means is different from the other ones**

First lets get the simple and plain table with tapply, in order to do that we must prepare the clean and recode the variables. Ftgr_fedgov must be a numeric, and pid_3 a factor with 3 levels.
I recode the levels that arent numeric "1"..."99" (missing values etc) to NA, which in my case are the first 8 levels returned by the `levels()` function. Notice that i have factor beacuse i specified that when reading the spps .sav file in the first lines.

```
levels(data$ftgr_fedgov)[1:8] <- NA
```

coerce to factor to numeric values

```
data$ftgt_fedgov <- as.numeric(data$ftgr_fedgov)
```

use an anonimous function with ta to get rid of the NA with `na.rm = T`

```
the.means <-tapply(data$ftgt_fedgov, data$pid_3, function(x) mean(x,na.rm = T))

meantab <- cbind(the.means)

colnames(meantab) <- "Mean Federal Gov rating"

print(meantab)
```

Console output:

```
     Mean Federal Gov rating
Dem           32.81931
Ind           23.73232
Rep           19.51978
```

Now lets go with the ANOVA:

```
myanova <-anova(lm(data = data, ftgt_fedgov ~ pid_3))

print(myanova)
```

Console output:

```
  Analysis of Variance Table

Response: ftgt_fedgov
Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
pid_3        2  164624   82312  342.58 < 2.2e-16 ***
  Residuals 5426 1303697     240                      
---
  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

So we have enough evidence to reject the null, now we can look at which group is different there are many methods to do this, the most common one is Tukey.

```
myanova <- aov(data$ftgt_fedgov ~ data$pid_3)

TukeyHSD(myanova)
```

Console output:

```
  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = data$ftgt_fedgov ~ data$pid_3)

$`data$pid_3`
            diff        lwr        upr     p adj
Ind-Dem  -9.086995 -10.217986  -7.956004     0
Rep-Dem -13.299528 -14.576857 -12.022198     0
Rep-Ind  -4.212533  -5.515013  -2.910053     0
```

In this case, all the three groups means are different (p adj)

you can see this with:

```
par(mfcol = c(1,2))
boxplot(data$ftgt_fedgov ~ data$pid_3, main = "Federal Government Thermometer Rating",
        col = c("lightblue","lightgoldenrodyellow","pink"))
plot(TukeyHSD(myanova))
```

[image: boxplot & tukey]

Also, you will need to validate the model looking at the residuals, the normality of the varible subsets etc but it seems to me that the assignment does not require that.

## Extra assignment

My hipothesis is that people that attend more often to 
religious services are least favorable to the legalization of marihuna.

DV = pot_legal3
IV = relig_attend

Both variables are factors so i use a `chisq.test()` with my table.

```
t1 <- table(data$relig_attend,data$pot_legal3)[,1:3] # removed weird column with [,1:3]

ht <- chisq.test() 

ht
```

Console output:

```
Pearson s Chi-squared test

data:  table(data$relig_attend, data$pot_legal3)[, 1:3]
X-squared = 470.58, df = 8, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

The p value is less than 0.001, we have enough evidence to reject the null hipotesis of independence.

Now lets check the standarized residuals to check for the direction of the dependence. with a plot

```
library(ggplot2)

# chi & table into data.frame
df1 <- as.data.frame(t1)
df1$res <- as.vector(round(ht$stdres,2))
df1$exp <- as.vector(round(ht$expected,0))
df1$obv <- as.vector(ht$observed)

ggplot(df1,aes(Var1,Var2,fill = res, label = paste(df1$obv," / ",df1$exp,"\n",df1$res,sep = "")))+
  geom_raster()+
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", mid = "white",high = "red")+
  geom_text()+
  guides( fill = guide_colorbar(title.position = "top"))+
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top")+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.text.y  = element_text(angle = 90, size = 14, hjust = 0.5),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
        plot.caption = element_text(face = "italic"),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.direction = "horizontal",
        legend.key.height = unit(1,"mm"),
        legend.key.width = unit(14,"mm"),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 10),
        legend.title.align = 0.5,
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,face = "bold.italic", size = 20, colour = "darkseagreen" )) +
  labs(title ="Pot & God",
       y = "Marihuana legalization" ,
       x = "Religious service attendance",
       fill = "Standarized residuals",
       caption  = "Data: SAGE NES2012     N: 5440",
       subtitle = "Observer / expected")
```

[image: pot & god]

Comment: Thank you very much! When I follow your example but use my own dataset, I get this(this comment window is difficult to write in so I will try to describe what I get:  I enter print (tbl.MV) then the output is 'voted' the next line is 'male 0 1 2 3' then the next is '0 1 0 0 0' next '1 0 572 230 2267' next '2 0 537 173 2137'. Thus I am not sure what I am getting here...

Comment: Mmmm it could be the data format make sure that is a `factor` with two categories i am asuming that the data is presented like in the Aids2 ( one column Male/female other voted/not voted). Can you provide a link to the dataset ? or edit the questión with the console output of  `str(your.data)`

Comment: Is this your data ? NES2012 https://edge.sagepub.com/pollock/student-resources/an-spss-companion-to-political-analysis-5th-edition/datasets

Comment: Yes, that is the dataset. I am blown away by your generosity here, thank you very much!

Comment: If you still have problems or doubts feel free to ask. I think all the problems you had where caused by working with a list instead of a data.frame and missing values or weird categorys..